# How can I restore Windows 10 update history?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

My Windows Update was stuck at 45% trying to install the update KB3124262. I tried to relaunch the Windows Update and then I restarted the PC but the update was never going to end.

I searched online for a solution and I found [this guide](http://www.thewindowsclub.com/windows-update-stuck-downloading-updates). It worked and now my Windows Update is working again.

The only side effect is that I lost all the history about previous updates in `Settings / Update & security / Advanced options / View your update history`.

Is there any way to restore the history or make Windows to regenerate the list?
I'm using Windows 10 Pro.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: **You cannot restore the history**  Your actions permanently cleared the data.

Comment: @Ramhound I still have the files if that can help

Comment: http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/quick-and-easy-way-list-all-windows-updates-installed-your-system.htm